# Weird Facebook API behavior, read group feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got strange behavior when using the FB Graph API to read the feed of a group I am administrating. Everybody in this group is posting YouTube links and I wanted to write an App to crawl them all into a nice list.

But depending on the user who posted I get one of the following results:

a) type=video and everything is fine
b) type=status and I have to parse the link from the message instead of having a link field
c) type=status and the link is not even in the message
d) some users' postings are not in the feed at all

Does anybody know how to really obtain all message? I can see those posts including the links perfectly well using the Facebook web site...

Already tried to give each and every access right to my app, didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the "problem": The result depends on the privacy settings of the user. Don't know why I can see the posts in the group but cannot automatically crawl it, only thing that happens now: I can't use the Facebook API but have to use some kind of HTML-parsing-crawler. Don't know why FB forces me to do that.